# How to use **test in c++?

Tags: c++

How can I use **pointer in c++? When I use *pointer[] I know how to access one element, but how can I access the elements of **pointer?

Comment: Are you asking about syntax in declarations, or expressions?

Comment: Refer to K&R then come back if you are still lost.

Comment: **(pointer + index) ? eg. if you want to access the 5th index **(pointer + 5);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `**` notation in C indicates a pointer to a pointer.  The elements of a `**` element are just single pointers and can be accessed using normal pointer operations.

```
char value = 'c';
char* pValue = &value;
char** ppValue  = &pValue;

char* pAnotherValue = *ppValue;
```

Getting back to the actual type which is double pointed to just requires an extra dererence operation

```
char value2 = **ppValue; // value2 == 'c'
```

Answer (score 1):

In exactly the same way.